# loading values from `require(file)` into local variables

Tags: module, lua

Sorry if this is an FAQ but if some  lib.lua returns a table of local functions e.g.

```
return {readCsv=readCsv, sumList=sumList, printHelp=printHelp}
```

and file2.lua imports it using

```
local lib=require("lib")
```

is there some programmatic way to automate the loading of the `lib` values into the local space? So i **DON'T** have to keep doing e.g.

```
local readCsv,sumList,printHelp=lib.readCsv,lib.sumList,lib.printHelp
```

I know its standard practice in LUA and it properly does not annoy many people. But it happens so often that I was wondering if there was a standard shortcut.

(Note: Just to be clear, I know how to make them **globals** by loading them into `_ENV` but that is exactly what I do not want.)

Comment: What do you think is the benefit of using `local`s, and do you think that this would negate that benefit?

Comment: i want to do it programmatically. automate the import into the local space

Comment: @TimMenzies: The question is more why you feel like this is important. Is typing `lib.` really so offensive?

Comment: how is that "programmatical way" supposed to know which scope you want those variables local to? this limited namespace is actually a good thing. why throw it away? just to save a few keystrokes?

Answer (score 1):

Since, it's just a regular table that is being returned by `require`, you can "unpack" that table to turn it into a list of values:

```lua
-- return values as both array and hash
return {readCsv, sumList, printHelp,
  readCsv=readCsv, sumList=sumList, printHelp=printHelp}

-- then do
local readCsv,sumList,printHelp = (table.unpack or unpack)(require "lib")
```

The order of returned/assigned values will obviously matter.

If somebody still wants to use a "regular" syntax with `local lib = require "lib"`, it will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, local variables are statically declared constructs. They're known at compile-time and cannot (generally) be allocated at runtime. Even the number of locals that an individual function holds is known at compile-time, even if the values held in them are not known until the function object is created.

As such, there is no dynamic mechanism to dump the contents of a table into a runtime-defined number of local variables.

The closest you could do is to parse the Lua script *text* manually to find all of the `require` statements, do those `require` yourself, and parse the tables to generate a sequence of `local` declarations that you will insert into the appropriate place in your Lua script text. You would then compile that script and use it.

But this is a huge amount of work just to get rid of `lib.`. It's just not worth it.

Comment: Maybe you want to say "dump a runtime-defined number of local variables into the contents of a table" where the latter has the *static* size so it is impossible to do the dump.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, I came  up with a function that simplifies importing. Now I sort of agree with @NicolBolas that is all a little "cancer of the semi-colon" but heh,  its short  and  optional (only a few lines of  code, does not mess with usual LUA module conventions)

`get"file"` requires the  file and unpacks results in alphabetical order. Kind of analogous  to the  Python command

```
from file import *
```

`get"file thing1 thing2.."`  requires the  file and unpacks only thing1 thing2. Kind of analogous to the Python command

```
from file import thing1,thing2
```

e.g. heres a file that returns  some code:

```lua
-- file = cc.lua
function fun1() print(1) end
function fun2() print(2) end
function fun3() print(3) end
function fun4() print(4) end
function fun5() print(5) end

return  {fun3=fun3, fun1=fun1, fun2=fun2, funs5=fun5, fun4=fun4}
```

Here's  one example of usage (unpack all). Note that the sub-module (`cc.lua`) can return  its things in any  order at all and this code will unpack them in alpha order:

```lua
-- file = gettest1.lua
local get=require"get"
local fun1,fun2,fun3,fun4,fun5=get"cc"

fun5()
```

And here's the other  usage  where we can unpack somethings, in any order we want:

```lua
-- file = gettest2.lua
local get=require"get"
local fun3,fun1=get"cc fun3 fun1"

fun1()
```

And here's the code for the  `get.lua` file that holds the `get` function

```lua
-- file = get.lua
local function get(spec)
  local gets, keys,out={},{},{}
  for get in string.gmatch(spec, "([^ ]+)") do gets[#gets+1]= get end
  local results = require(table.remove(gets,1))
  if   #gets>0 
  then  keys= gets
  else  for key,_ in pairs(results) do keys[#keys+1] = key end
        table.sort(keys)
  end
  for _,key in ipairs(keys) do out[#out+1] = results[key] end
  return table.unpack(out) 
end

return get
```

Improvements? Suggestions? Comments?

Comment: actually, this gets kinda cute (IMHO).  the examples above could be even simple. gettest1.lua could  be just `local fun1,fun2,fun3,fun4,fun5=require("get")"cc"` and  gettest2.lua could be just `local fun3,fun1=require("get")"cc fun3 fun1"`.